# I'm doing a turtlebot-based project: should I just install indigo?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, rocon, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have spent a lot of time with Kinetic Kame the past couple of weeks as I read *Gentle Introduction to ROS* and do basic tutorials online. Now as I delve into the project that is the point (a turtleBot like project), I need to install Racon and the turtlebot stack. Unfortunately I'm not finding them for Kinetic. For instance, for both Turtlebot and Rocon, it seems the latest support tags stop with Indigo:
http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TurtleBot
http://wiki.ros.org/rocon

Should I go ahead and switch to Indigo, or am I missing the place to get them for Kinetic? Should I uninstall Kinetic Kame to avoid collisions, or will I be ok just going through the standard install instructions for indigo, having both installed on my system? I'm sort of sad, as I really like Kinetic Kane and have grown sort of attached to that little red fella....

Does anyone know whether these packages (turbleBot/Rocon) will be supported for future ROS versions beyond Indigo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240650/i%27m-doing-a-turtlebot-based-project:-should-i-just-install-indigo?/) by [neuronet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27484/neuronet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2016-07-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2016-07-29**:
rule Nr. 1 : never ever get emotionally attached to anything in the robotics field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The TurtleBot is mostly release in Kinetic. The higher level packages lag as they have to wait for their dependencies to be released sequentially into each rosdistro.

It's not uncommon for robot support packages to only do the LTS releases and lag by 6-12 months from the first rosdistro release. I suspect what you're looking for will be released into Kinetic but may not be available yet.

You should be able to use the indigo version from source on top of Kinetic if you want to push ahead.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2